AppState.addEventListener does not fire when app comes active from power down sleep mode
AppState goes background on power button press.
But does not fired when app is activated.
Platform: IOS
package.json
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "^7.0.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^8.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "1.6.4",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "create-react-class": "^15.7.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "eas-cli": "^0.49.0",
    "expo": "^51.0.8",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.1",
    "expo-camera": "^15.0.9",
    "expo-checkbox": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "^15.0.5",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-location": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
    "project-can-json": "^1.0.1",
    "project-react-accordion": "^1.0.4",
    "project-react-mvc": "^1.5.4",
    "project-rest-client": "^1.2.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.74.1",
    "react-native-check-version": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.13.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-fetch-api": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.11.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-sse": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-store-version": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-webview": "13.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

js code
let appStateSubscription_3 = undefined;    
if (appStateSubscription_3 !== undefined) appStateSubscription_3.remove();
        appStateSubscription_3 = AppState.addEventListener('change', nextAppState => {

            console.log('APP.JS CHANGE:' + nextAppState);
        });

console result:
LOG  APP.JS CHANGE:inactive
LOG  APP.JS CHANGE:background
expected console result:
APP.JS CHANGE:active
there is nothing to add
